# How does "L1 distance" path-following for fixed-wings work?

Tags: fixed-wing

I was told that the "L1 distance" method is one of the simpler methods for guiding a fixed-wing aircraft along a path. It sounds like a path-following method for fixed-wing aircraft that compensates for the inability of fixed-wings to follow an exact path (unlike helicopters, which can easily change directions). How does the "L1 distance" guidance method work exactly?